# SQL query optimization select or inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I have a problem of slowness on one of my requests which is a long time.
I tested to use INDEX, without results.
I was advised to put inner join instead of my slect but I do not see how to do for different operations on the same table.

Tables :

```
 CREATE TABLE `cryptos` (
  `uuid` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `shortname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  [...]
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `cryptos_infos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 [...]
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `fk_cryptoid` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_cryptoid` (`fk_cryptoid`),
  CONSTRAINT `cryptos_infos_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_cryptoid`) REFERENCES `cryptos` (`uuid`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `eventcryptorelations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  [...]
  `fk_cryptoid` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_eventid` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_cryptoid` (`fk_cryptoid`),
  KEY `fk_eventid` (`fk_eventid`),
  CONSTRAINT `eventcryptorelations_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_cryptoid`) REFERENCES `cryptos` (`uuid`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `eventcryptorelations_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_eventid`) REFERENCES `events` (`uuid`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `uuid` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  [...]
  PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `github_activ_repos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  [...]
  `fk_githubid` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_githubid` (`fk_githubid`),
  CONSTRAINT `github_activ_repos_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_githubid`) REFERENCES `github_info_repos` (`uuid`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `github_info_repos` (
  `uuid` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `idgit` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  [...]
  `fk_cryptoid` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`),
  KEY `fk_cryptoid` (`fk_cryptoid`),
  CONSTRAINT `github_info_repos_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_cryptoid`) REFERENCES `cryptos` (`uuid`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `prices` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `open` double DEFAULT NULL,
  [...]
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `fk_cryptoid` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_cryptoid` (`fk_cryptoid`),
  CONSTRAINT `prices_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_cryptoid`) REFERENCES `cryptos` (`uuid`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `trendsSearches` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `formattedTime` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `fk_cryptoid` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_cryptoid` (`fk_cryptoid`),
  CONSTRAINT `trendsSearches_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_cryptoid`) REFERENCES `cryptos` (`uuid`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `twitter_activs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  [...]
  `fk_twitterid` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_twitterid` (`fk_twitterid`),
  CONSTRAINT `twitter_activs_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_twitterid`) REFERENCES `twitter_infos` (`idtwitter`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `twitter_infos` (
  `idtwitter` double NOT NULL,
 [...]
  `fk_cryptoid` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idtwitter`),
  KEY `fk_cryptoid` (`fk_cryptoid`),
  CONSTRAINT `twitter_infos_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_cryptoid`) REFERENCES `cryptos` (`uuid`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `volumes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `volumefrom` double DEFAULT NULL,
  [...]
  `fk_cryptoid` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_cryptoid` (`fk_cryptoid`),
  CONSTRAINT `volumes_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_cryptoid`) REFERENCES `cryptos` (`uuid`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I reduced the tables for better understanding.

Explanation of the query:

I need to get the first 100 entries sorted by the 'rank' field found on the cryptos_info table.
With the latest entry price and the price of 24 hours ago.
With other information on other tables such as an entry on the volume, on the table github ....

Query :

```
select cryptos_infos.rank, cryptos.shortname, cryptos.imageurl, cryptos_infos.coinminde,
(SELECT open FROM prices WHERE prices.fk_cryptoid = cryptos.uuid and prices.date LIKE '2018-09-16%' order by prices.date DESC limit 1) as priceone,
 (SELECT open FROM prices WHERE prices.fk_cryptoid = cryptos.uuid and prices.date LIKE '2018-09-16%' order by prices.date DESC limit 1) as pricetwo , 
(SELECT P.open FROM prices P WHERE P.fk_cryptoid = cryptos.uuid order by P.createdAt DESC limit 1) as open,
 (select count(E.hot) from events E where E.uuid in (select EC.fk_eventid from eventcryptorelations EC where EC.fk_cryptoid = cryptos.uuid) and E.hot = 1) as hot,
 (SELECT value FROM trendsSearches WHERE trendsSearches.fk_cryptoid = cryptos.uuid order by trendsSearches.time DESC limit 1) as trenone,
 (SELECT value FROM trendsSearches WHERE trendsSearches.fk_cryptoid = cryptos.uuid  order by trendsSearches.time DESC LIMIT 1,1) as trentwo,
 (select GAR.stars from github_activ_repos GAR where GAR.fk_githubid = ( select uuid from github_info_repos GIR, github_activ_repos GR where GIR.fk_cryptoid = cryptos.uuid and GIR.uuid = GR.fk_githubid order by GR.stars DESC limit 1) order by GAR.time DESC limit 1) as gitone, 
(select GAR.stars from github_activ_repos GAR where GAR.fk_githubid = ( select uuid from github_info_repos GIR, github_activ_repos GR where GIR.fk_cryptoid = cryptos.uuid and GIR.uuid = GR.fk_githubid order by GR.stars DESC limit 1) order by GAR.time DESC limit 1,1) as gittwo,
 (SELECT abonnees FROM twitter_activs WHERE twitter_activs.fk_twitterid = (select idtwitter from twitter_infos where twitter_infos.fk_cryptoid = cryptos.uuid) and twitter_activs.createdAt LIKE '2018-09-16%' order by twitter_activs.createdAt DESC limit 1) as abotone, 
(SELECT abonnees FROM twitter_activs WHERE twitter_activs.fk_twitterid = (select idtwitter from twitter_infos where twitter_infos.fk_cryptoid = cryptos.uuid) and twitter_activs.createdAt LIKE '2018-09-16%' order by twitter_activs.createdAt DESC limit 1) as abottwo 
from cryptos, cryptos_infos where cryptos.uuid = cryptos_infos.fk_cryptoid and cryptos_infos.rank is not null  order by cryptos_infos.rank ASC limit 100;
```

Info :
All request = 30s

Request - select on table prices = 1.23s

Lines where the problem of slowness:

```
(SELECT open FROM prices WHERE prices.fk_cryptoid = cryptos.uuid and prices.date LIKE '2018-09-23%' order by prices.date DESC limit 1) as priceone,
 (SELECT open FROM prices WHERE prices.fk_cryptoid = cryptos.uuid and prices.date LIKE '2018-09-23%' order by prices.date DESC limit 1) as pricetwo , 
(SELECT P.open FROM prices P WHERE P.fk_cryptoid = cryptos.uuid order by P.createdAt DESC limit 1) as open,
```

Comment: Simplify your query.  Remove expressions from the `SELECT` to find which are causing the performance problem.

Comment: Edit: the probléme is on tables prices ( ~2 000 000 lines).

Comment: Post your problem "https://dba.stackexchange.com/" , Hope you will find a solution there.

Comment: @Suresh Why? This forum seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

First, do not use `like` for dates.  Instead:

```
(SELECT open FROM prices p WHERE p.fk_cryptoid = cryptos.uuid and p.date >= '2018-09-23' AND p.date < '2018-09-24' order by p.date DESC limit 1) as priceone,
(SELECT open FROM prices p WHERE p.fk_cryptoid = cryptos.uuid and p.date >= '2018-09-23' AND p.date < '2018-09-24' order by p.date DESC limit 1) as pricetwo , 
(SELECT P.open FROM prices P WHERE P.fk_cryptoid = cryptos.uuid order by P.createdAt DESC limit 1) as open,
```

For this, you can try an index on `prices(fk_cryptoid, p.date, open)` and `prices(fk_cryptoid, createdAt, open)`.

You may need to be a bit more drastic.  The goal is to use an index for the subquery.  I'm not sure if MySQL is smart enough to do that in these cases.

You may need to change the existing `date` column to be just a date and add a new datetime column with both the date/time (or just a time column).  Then you can phrase the subquery as:

```
(SELECT open FROM prices p WHERE p.fk_cryptoid = cryptos.uuid and p.date = '2018-09-23' order by p.datetime DESC limit 1) as priceone,
```

And the index you want is on `(fk_cryptoid, date, datetime, open)`.